# Spanning tree of a Petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am asked to find the number of spanning tree of a petersen graph. I have to tried to count it but i realise i can't because there are so many different combination.

Are there any method that i can actually calculate it?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

The number is 2000.
Refer chapter 6, Algebraic graph theory, Norman Biggs. 
Note that Petersen graph is the complement of the line graph of K5.